# Remove select option if sum 2 select option greater than sum by Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I want to check 2 select option. Both of them have 9 option with value from 0 to 9.
You can use one of 2 code below

```
<select name="adult" class="select-people">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    ......
    <option value="9">9</option>
</select>

<select name="child" class="select-people">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    ......
    <option value="9">9</option>
</select>
```

My problem is sum of adult and child is not greater than 9. So when I select 
8 adult, in child select, options from 3 to 9 will be removed. And when I select 5 adult, in child select, options from 6 to 9 will be removed. And the same with the child select.
Thank you so much !

Big thanks to 2 buddy for answer me
These code worked for me:

From **jQuerybeast**

```
$(document).on("change",".select-people[name=adult]",function(){
  var x = 11 - $(this).val();
  $(".select-people[name=child] option").removeAttr("disabled");
  $(".select-people[name=child] option[value="+x+"]").attr("disabled","disabled").nextAll().attr("disabled","disabled");
})

$(document).on("change",".select-people[name=adult]",function(){
  var x = 11 - $(this).val();
  $(".select-people[name=child] option").show();
  $(".select-people[name=child] option[value="+x+"]").hide().nextAll().hide()
})
```

From **Foram Trada**

```
$(document).on("change",".select-people[name=adult]",function(){
  var x = 11 - $(this).val();
  $(".select-people[name=child] option").removeAttr("disabled");
  $(".select-people[name=child] option[value="+x+"]").attr("disabled","disabled").nextAll().attr("disabled","disabled");
})

$(document).on("change",".select-people[name=child]",function(){
  var x = 11 - $(this).val();
  $(".select-people[name=adult] option").removeAttr("disabled");
  $(".select-people[name=adult] option[value="+x+"]").attr("disabled","disabled").nextAll().attr("disabled","disabled");
})
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is there any example or fiddle you may have?

Comment: I have tried many ways but I can only delete 1 element at a time.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to delete and not disable?

Comment: Oh, I forget that I just need to disable them. Can you help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To disable:**

```
$(document).on("change",".select-people[name=adult]",function(){
  var x = 11 - $(this).val();
  $(".select-people[name=child] option").removeAttr("disabled");
  $(".select-people[name=child] option[value="+x+"]").attr("disabled","disabled").nextAll().attr("disabled","disabled");
})
```

**To Hide ("delete"):**

```
$(document).on("change",".select-people[name=adult]",function(){
  var x = 11 - $(this).val();
  $(".select-people[name=child] option").show();
  $(".select-people[name=child] option[value="+x+"]").hide().nextAll().hide()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that you can do with,

Example: If adult= 4 then child will show 1,2,3,4,5,6. And also vice-versa.

```js
$(document).on("change",".select-people[name=adult]",function(){
  var x = 11 - $(this).val();
  $(".select-people[name=child] option").removeAttr("disabled");
  $(".select-people[name=child] option[value="+x+"]").attr("disabled","disabled").nextAll().attr("disabled","disabled");
})

$(document).on("change",".select-people[name=child]",function(){
  var x = 11 - $(this).val();
  $(".select-people[name=adult] option").removeAttr("disabled");
  $(".select-people[name=adult] option[value="+x+"]").attr("disabled","disabled").nextAll().attr("disabled","disabled");
})
```

```html
   <select name="adult" class="select-people">
    <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
     <option value="3">3</option>
     <option value="4">4</option>
     <option value="5">5</option>
     <option value="6">6</option>
     <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
     <option value="9">9</option>
</select>

<select name="child" class="select-people">
   <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
     <option value="3">3</option>
     <option value="4">4</option>
     <option value="5">5</option>
     <option value="6">6</option>
     <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
     <option value="9">9</option>
</select>
```